# How to install ubuntu 12.04 desktop os using kickstart

Tags: 12.04, kickstart

I want to install ubuntu 12.04 desktop os using the kickstart can any one help me please

What type service need to install and on client install what to type where to type

Answer (score 0):

Google returns **tons** of links by "ubuntu 12.04 kickstart" query:
tutorials (for example, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KickstartCompatibility),
ready-to-use scripts (https://gist.github.com/ludo/3652811) and so on.

Reading of them should be your first step before asking questions.